# How to open dropdown menu on right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to make a dropdown not always open on right in twitter bootsrapper? sometimes there is no space on right specially in mobile devices like iphones, I'd like it to open on left instead

Please have a look at my example here:

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Regular link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown open">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop4" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop4">
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop5" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown 2 <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul id="menu2" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop5">
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop5" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Open on left <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul id="menu3" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop5">
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
</diV>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/1557/

I would like the last button "Open on left" to open it's menu on left rather than right.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With css set the dropdown-menu item to have a margin-left value that is negative.